# Zabbix trigger expression external check

Tags: triggers, expression, zabbix

I created a external check that returns a value formatted like :

```
File System Storage Percent:12.34
```

Is that possible to create a trigger that check if the value > 50% ?

```
{my_host:my_external_check.py.str(File System Storage Percent:50.00)}=1
```

I saw that regexp exists but it does not return the value found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script to return the value without the extra text - like `12.34`. Then you can use the usual Zabbix trigger functions `last()`, `min()`, `avg()`, `max()` and others.